# Wordpress with htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I just made up a blog on wordpress and now by json i display those post on my website. Now i want to make htaccess that whenever someone clicks on the post on wordpress it will forwarding him to my website, but it doesn't work. Any ideas? :)

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule ^p=/([0-9]+)$ http://companyname2.companyname2.pl/site/pl/post.html#!/?categoryID=XYZ&postID=$1 [L]
```

http://wordpress.wordpress.pl/?p=223 -> http://companyname.companyname.pl/site/pl/post.html#!/?categoryID=XYZ&postID=233

Comment: What happens when you hit the example url?

Comment: I just solve this by:
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=([0-9]+)$
    RewriteRule ^.*$ http://companyname.companyname.pl/site/pl/post.html#!/?categoryID=XYZ&postID=%1 [R,L,NE]